# how to close notification when trigger clicked twice or outside element in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a notification widget that will appear when I click the trigger and disappear when I click the trigger twice or click elsewhere in outside element.
How to do that?

```
$('.swt').click(function(){
  $('.swt').removeClass('active');
  $('.ctx').removeClass('ctx-active');
  $(this).addClass('active');
});

var ccd = 1;

$('#add').click(function(){
  $('#ad').addClass('ctx-active');
});


$('#msg').click(function(){
  $('#ms').addClass('ctx-active');
});

$('#notif').click(function(){
  $('#no').addClass('ctx-active');
});

$('#sst').click(function(){
  $('#show div').removeClass('ctx-active');
});
```

[demo code](https://jsfiddle.net/bsx7vLvc/)

Comment: To create a notification which may dismiss when you click outside the element you need to add an element (full width and maybe transparent) to capture that click (tap) for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change the `removeClass` and `addClass` with [toggleClass](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/html_toggleclass.asp). Here's the [Documentation on toggleClass](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/).

Here's a fixed [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/640wcoom/).

For 'close when click outside', you will have to add a transparent `div` with full width and height behind `#tooltip`, and add a `click eventListener`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `dblclick` for double-click event handler and inside the event handler you can add checking like this one:

```
$(document).dblclick(function(e) {
  if (e.target.id != "show" && !$(e.target).parents("#show").size()) {
     //remove class
  }
});
```

For the implementation you can see here : [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bsx7vLvc/6/)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for answers.
Finally i find the result for all the problems.
i just use sibling() and toggleclass() to fix the problems.
this is the update demo.

[demo code](https://jsfiddle.net/nurul/bsx7vLvc/9/%60)

```
$('#add').click(function(){
  $('#ms').removeClass('ctx-active');
  $('#no').removeClass('ctx-active');
  $('#ad').toggleClass('ctx-active');
  $('#add').siblings().removeClass('active');
  $(this).toggleClass('active');
});


$('#msg').click(function(){
  $('#no').removeClass('ctx-active');
  $('#ad').removeClass('ctx-active');
  $('#ms').toggleClass('ctx-active');
  $('#msg').siblings().removeClass('active');
  $(this).toggleClass('active');
});

$('#notif').click(function(){
  $('#ms').removeClass('ctx-active');
  $('#ad').removeClass('ctx-active');
  $('#no').toggleClass('ctx-active');
  $('#notif').siblings().removeClass('active');
  $(this).toggleClass('active');
});

$('#sst').click(function(){
  $('#show div').removeClass('ctx-active');
});

$('#ss').click(function(){
  $('.ctx').removeClass('ctx-active');
  $('.swt').removeClass('active');
});`
```